# Why isn't this if statement working with item from a array?

Tags: php

Im not sure why this isn't working, can anyone help? Im trying to see if 
*$lines[$y]* is the same as *"../../Files/Person/$username/files/$share_person_post"* but even if it is, it isn't running through the code.

```
if (file_exists("../../Files/Person/$username/shared.txt")) {
  $lines = file("../../Files/Person/$username/shared.txt");
  $size = sizeof($lines);
  $size = $size - 1;

  $shared_location = "Unknown";
  for($y = 0; $y <= $size; $y++) {
    echo $lines[$y];
    if ($lines[$y] == "../../Files/Person/$username/files/$share_person_post") {
      echo "Here";
      $z = $y + 1;
      $shared_location = $lines[$z];
      $fmsg = "<p>This file is already shared at $shared_location</p>";
      $ex = "0";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($lines[$y])` and see why the values aren't matching

Comment: `var_dump($lines[$y])` and `var_dump("../../Files/Person/$username/files/$share_person_post");`. Prob need to `trim` or `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`

Comment: Did you try to `echo intval($lines[$y] == "../../Files/Person/$username/files/$share_person_post")`? This will clearly say if they are the same or not.

Comment: I suggest you use `count()` instead of `sizeof()`. `sizeof()` is only an alias of `count()` and does not mean the same for people coming from other languages like C. Most PHP devs will use `count()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using explode, I know for me when I grab text files, they are all one long string.  It might be my server or php version, but its worth a shot.

```
if (file_exists("../../Files/Person/$username/shared.txt"))
{
    $data = file("../../Files/Person/$username/shared.txt");
    $lines = explode("\n",$data);
    $size = count($lines);
    $size = $size - 1;

    $shared_location = "Unknown";
    for($y = 0; $y <= $size; $y++)
    {
        echo $lines[$y];
        if($lines[$y] == "../../Files/Person/$username/files/$share_person_post")
        {
            echo "Here";
            $z = $y + 1;
            $shared_location = $lines[$z];
            $fmsg = "<p>This file is already shared at 
            $shared_location</p>";
            $ex = "0";
        }
   }
```

}

Comment: When i do this i just get `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/user/share.php on line 33`

Comment: You will need an indicator between the paths.

The file is showing up as one long string.

Like below: 
    ../../Files/Person/$username/shared.txt../../Files/Person/$username/shared.txt
You could add some symbol between the paths.

../../Files/Person/$username/shared.txt|    ../../Files/Person/$username/shared.txt

Then change the explode to.
explode("|",$data);

The original explode was looking for "\n" which means next line.

Comment: No problem, best of luck.